# U-SQL project in VS2017 -There is a missing project subtype. Subtype: '{416D63FD-0477-49AA-A954-A7C5B95A9B51} is unsupported by this installation

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, u-sql

I use `Visual Studio Community 2017`.
I need to create a new project of `U-SQL Project`.

[image]

When I do that, I have this error.

[image]

```
There is a missing project subtype. 
Subtype: '{416D63FD-0477-49AA-A954-A7C5B95A9B51} is unsupported by this installation.
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, R Tools for Visual Studio in 2017 updates the assembly binding redirect for all Visual Studio which causes conflicts for others.  Could you try to go to the Visual Studio Installer, and uninstall the Data Science workload (which contains R Tools) and see if the issue goes away?